I am getting the following error :"Suppressed: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column"
When I am creating a dataframe on parquet files and writing it into Oracle DB, I am getting such error:
"Suppressed: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column"
The things I have checked:

The encoding in both oracle and spark is compatible and correct.
The source for parquet is oracle DB itself and target for the parquet is also Oracle DB and both the databases are having same encoding.
The datatype of the field has been modified as CLOB still I am getting the issue.
The datatype of the dataframe(created on the parquet file) field is string and the string length is maximum 52.

If you require more information please let me know, as I have searched about it too much and can not find anything.

In general we tend to see this error when a client attempts to bind a large string that when multiplied by 4 for a multibyte characterset overflows the 4000 byte limit in Oracle. Depending on the database characterset, try limiting the size of any large string to 2000 chars or even 1000 chars.  If the issue is with a real LOB, however, you would need to ensure your client can handle LOBs and ensure you are treating them correctly - they work differently than most datatypes so it is probable that extra steps are needed to handle them. You may have to code the LOB write yourself using dbms_lob.

Hi @PaulW , as I mentioned in source these fields are not clob field.However I am using clob in target , it still throws the error.

Please re-read my comment carefully. I did not talk only about LOBs. The main reason folks get this error is because of the sizing of the client variable that you are binding to the SQL. It is not a database issue, but a client variable type/sizing issue. Shrink your client variable to < 1000 chars and it should go into a varchar2(4000) regardless of characterset. If you have > 4000 char data, you will need to employ special calls to handle LOB writes.

Got this error fixed , turned out I was using the environment (EMR) for the spark cluster which by default supports JDK 17 and I was passing the jdbc driver ojdbc8 which is not compatible with JDK 17 so I upgraded the ojdbc version and used ojdbc11.

Sounds good. By changing your client database driver you changed the logic of how client variables are bound and datatypes handled. Glad to hear it worked.

If the problem's solved now, you could either delete the question or you could write up an answer and mark it as resolved.
